# Angular form validation in a "fake" submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms

I have a form in a page with 2 buttons. One trigger a function to calculate a price and the other one is the real submit of the form.

This is a simple example:

```
<form novalidate name="formStep1">
  <select ng-model="address" required>
     <option></option>
     <option></option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" ng-model="weight" />

  <label>{{price}}</label>

  <button ng-click="getPrice()" />
  <button value="submit"/>

</form>
```

I need to trigger all validators like $error and $submitted to put ng-class on the select and input tags of the form because when do the function I need all the inputs with text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `form` you have two fields which don't have the `name`s attribute assign to it. To make those field as a part of form you need to assign `name` attribute to those element. Once you add the `name` attribute to them angular form validation will start showing its infect.

You could also have `submitted` flag to keep a track of form has been submitted by `getPrice()` method or not. On click of that make that flag to `true` & use it as while doing a validation using `ng-class`

**Markup**

```
<form novalidate name="formStep1">
  <select ng-class="{'error': submitted && formStep1.address.$invalid}" name="address" ng-model="address" required>
     <option></option>
     <option></option>
  </select>

  <input ng-class="{'error': submitted && formStep1.weight.$invalid}" type="text" name="weight" ng-model="weight" />

  <label>{{price}}</label>

  <button ng-click="submitted=true; getPrice()" />
  <button value="submit"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Ok so, how can i put ng-class to show error when select or input are empty when click on getPrice?

I used to do the validations with :

ng-class="{error: formStep1.$error.valid && !formStep1.$submitted"}

If I can't submit the form with ng-click i can't have $submitted can I?

Comment: Yes but when i put names the ng-click function doesnt put form in submitted status

Comment: @RogerNomen could you create a plunkr & give it to me..I'll try to make it working

Comment: Until tomorrow i cant... I will fix it as i can and tomorrow we'll talk. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself with @Pankaj's help:

With all names in inputs and passing formStep1 as an argument in getPrice function I can access to input validation like:

```
$scope.getPrice = function (form) { 
  if(!form.nameOfInput.$dirty) { 
    form.nameOfInput.$invalid = true; 
  } else {
    // GET PRICE
  }
}
```

Is this a good aproach in case to need to validate inputs in a none submit button?